# Hooks and multiple instances of React in Gatsby app

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use `useState` in a simple function component in GatsbyJS but I'm getting a seemingly common error in React.

My stripped-down component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Header () {
    const [isOpen, toggleOpen] = useState(false);
    return ( 
        <header>
            <button onClick={() => toggleOpen( !isOpen )}>Click Me</button>
        </header>
    )
}
```

I get the following error:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
> function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See ***redacted to quell SO error*** for tips about how to debug and
>    fix this problem.

So I read up about the error on [this Facebook/React docs page](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) and have determined that my `react-dom` version is >16.8.0 (I'm using `^16.13.1`). My react version is the same.

I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with my component function (I basically copied the example from the docs).

The third thing, which I suspect is the issue, is multiple versions of react running simultaneously. When I run `npm ls react` I get:

```
+-- gatsby@2.24.73
| `-- gatsby-cli@2.12.107
|   `-- react@16.13.1  deduped
`-- react@16.13.1
```

I tried moving `react` and `react-dom` to `peerDependencies`, as per [this response](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991#issuecomment-692400501) from [this Github issues thread](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991), in my `package.json' but that didn't fix the problem, e.g:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  }
```

I also tried adding a `GATSBY_HOT_LOADER = “fast-refresh”` var in a `.env.development` file according to [this Gatsby thread](https://spectrum.chat/gatsby-js/general/invalid-hook-call-error-multiple-instances-of-react%7E26f20415-c03a-4898-8667-e2bf6225b5bf) but the issue persisted.

```
require("dotenv").config({
    path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
```

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-hello-world",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A simplified bare-bones starter for Gatsby",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "0BSD",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^2.24.73",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.4.21",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.3.16",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.6.40",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.3.34",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.5.17",
    "hamburgers": "^1.1.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.1.2",
    "prettier": "2.1.2"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  }
}
```

And environment info:

```
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.18362
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8300H CPU @ 2.30GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.16.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    npm: 6.13.4 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Browsers:
    Edge: 44.18362.449.0
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^2.24.73 => 2.24.73
    gatsby-image: ^2.4.21 => 2.4.21
    gatsby-plugin-sass: ^2.3.16 => 2.3.16
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^2.3.34 => 2.3.34
```

I've been using Gatsby without issues for some time now so I'm surprised by this error. I suspect it has to do with Gatsby running a version of React, although "deduped", and another version of React also running as seen when I run `npm ls react`.

Where can I go from here?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you created a minimal repo to reproduce the error? this kind of stuff is hard to debug seeing code alone :/

Comment: I've started a fresh install and am not receiving the error as of yet, so I'm going over my steps and if I find anything, I'll update my post. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up starting over and downloading a fresh copy of the gatsby-starter I was using and that's resolved the issue.

I think I inadvertently installed `react` and `react-dom` while I was trying to install a plugin at some point and having multiple versions of react running (one within gatsby) and one installed somewhere else in my project caused the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using React@16.13.1. Notably, the gatsby-starter currently only uses React@16.12.1. I ultimately came across an answer from Jeremy Albright on the Gatsby Spectrum that pointed out this could be related to `react-hot-loader` being deprecated.

Gatsby already has support instead for `fast-refresh`, you just have to enable the flag.

The fix that worked for me was to add `GATSBY_HOT_LOADER=fast-refresh` to my `.env` file.

[Source](https://spectrum.chat/gatsby-js/general/invalid-hook-call-error-multiple-instances-of-react%7E26f20415-c03a-4898-8667-e2bf6225b5bf)

Comment: Hey thanks, I also saw that comment from Jeremy on the Gatsby Spectrum chat but it didn't actually do anything for me. Not sure why or if we were facing the same issue but glad you found a solution to your problem. Maybe include the link to the chat in your post?

Comment: @DavidGaskin sorry to hear it didn't help. The link to the chat is hyperlinked under "Source" at the bottom of my post. Cheers.